# How could i add a condition stop to ettercap command?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, tshark, spoofing

I can stop manually the ettercap task with “q” key but i need add a condition stop to my python3 script to automate my process. Could someone help me?

Pd: sorry for my poor english.

Thanks,

Antonio.

Comment: We have language-specific versions of Stack Overflow now; if your language is one of them then you could use that.

Comment: Thanks. if you can understand me, i am ok! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about `ettercap`, or even what it is, but as a worst-case hackish solution you could send a `q` into ettercap when it's time to stop.

With a program like this:

```
import time

while not condition:
    time.sleep(0.01)
print("q")
```

you could run it like this:

```
python the_above_program.py | ettercap thing
```

and it would stop when the Python program detected it should.

Comment: For your information, ettercap is a spoofing arp attack free sw. You can look all ethernet traffic in your network with this sw. i need this sw for capture ethernet traffic between some devices in my job. Regards. Toni.

Comment: @toni If this solved your problem, please consider accepting this answer. You can do so by clicking the tick underneath the voting buttons until it turns green (double-clicking will not work). This gives me a +15 reputation bonus, gives you a +2 reputation bonus, and marks this question as "answered" so other people don't waste time answering it (unless they have a better answer).